# Graphics card fans very loud, no video/unable to boot

Tags: boot, graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply

So let's back up a few months. I came back from work one day to find my computer on (I remote desktop to it occasionally) but my graphics card (Gigabyte GTX 770 OC-2GB version) fans running very loudly and not having any video. I turned it off and back on but got no video and the fans were spinning very loudly.

I know the computer boots because if I turn it on and leave it run (while the gfx card displays no video and fans are still loudly spinning), I can remote desktop into it. I've also unplugged the power from it and plugged my HDMI into my motherboard and it works just fine there. I took my card over to a friend's house and we plugged it into his computer with no avail - it still outputted no video and the fans spun very loudly.

At that point, I believed the GFX card just up and died so I RMA'd it with Gigabyte. I just got the card back from them two days ago and so I plugged it back in and it worked just fine. I played games on it just fine and the fans were very quiet as they should be.

Today I get home from work and find my computer in the same state: on, but the graphics card fans were spinning very loudly and no video output. I turned it off and switched over to my CPU's integrated graphics which worked fine, but I cannot get my graphics card to work at all.

I've tried the following:

- Resetting CMOS & BIOS
- Booting with only one stick of RAM (I've tried both)
- Making sure my graphics card is in the correct PCI-E lane according to my mobo's manual
- Using DIsplayPort and/or HDMI.

None of which have worked.

Any suggestions?

My current build:

- Rosewill Thor V2
- Intel i7-4770K (stock clocked)
- [Gigabyte GA-Z87X-UD3H](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4481)
- Phanteks PH-TC12DX_BL
- XFX Pro 750W Black Edition Fully Modular
- [Gigabyte GTX 770 (factory overclocked)](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814125463&cm_re=gigabyte_gtx_770-_-14-125-463-_-Product)

I do have a brand new power supply laying around (Cooler Master V1200, fully modular @ 1200W) that I could try. Could it very likely be my current power supply? I just think it's weird because I've never had problems with my graphics card until very recently and I've had this build for around a year and a half now.

Thanks.

Comment: You used the same PCI-E cables I presume?

Comment: @Ramhound Correct. They're probably the only PCI-E cables I have. I could check my other fully modular power supply to see if it came with compatible PCI-E cables though.

Comment: The fact this happened twice indicates the power supply

Comment: @Ramhound That's what I was thinking, but I didn't want to have to deal with completely re-cabling my entire build until I really had to. I'll try to swap power supplies and see if that gives me anything good.

Comment: The fact you used the exact same power cable twice indicates that the problem but the graphics card is likely toast though

Comment: @Ramhound I've still yet to try switching power supplies, but I sincerely hope my graphics card isn't toast because I just got it back from Gigabyte after an RMA from before. Would Gigabyte fulfill another RMA so close to when the last one was?

Comment: Yes they will honor another RMA, every device you get has an RMA period, I wouldn't tell them it was caused by another device in your system though, just that the video card failed again. Also, have you made sure there aren't any cables in the way of the fan, and also made sure that both fans are actually spinning? One may be spinning at 100% to try and compensate for the other not spinning.

Comment: I will let you self-answer this question since I would only be guessing, even if I am 99% sure of the problem, I can't confirm myself

Comment: @Ramhound Well I tried it in my friend's PC and my own after using a different PSU and different cables, and it still didn't work. I'm thinking the PSU might've fried it again. So I'll be submitting another RMA and using my other PSU. Think it'd be worth it to RMA the PSU too?

Answer (score 0):

Check for accumulations of dust on the heatsinks of the CPU and on the GPU of the graphics card.  Also check for an accumulation of dust inside the power supply.  Any of these accumulations of dust can overheat that area enough to make the associated fan spin as fast as it can, while turning off most of the rest of the computer.  A few computers have still other parts with heatsinks that use fans; if your does, check there also.